# Conditional formating of duplicate cells in excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I cant seem to get his working. It either formats all the cells or skips cells for some reason. Keep in mind that I can't go based on the exact text in the cells since that document will change. I'm sure there is a formula for this but I can't seem to get it going.

Thanks for the help guys!

Heres what it looks like to begin with.

**Initial Image**

[image: Initial Image]

**I would like it to look like this.**

[image: After]

**Heres what it gives me.**

[image: What I have]

Thanks guys!

Comment: Why should "Inspecvision" be a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the following formulas in Conditional formatting based on `Excel Version`

[image]

---

**Method One:**

```
=LET(x, TEXTAFTER(B2," ",-1,1,1), (x="Inc.")+(x="Pub"))
```

---

Or, **Method Two:**

```
=OR(RIGHT(B2,4)="Inc.",RIGHT(B2,3)="Pub")
```

---

Using `COUNTIFS()` it will be like this:

```
=(COUNTIFS(B$2:B$40,B2,B$2:B$40,"*Inc.")+COUNTIFS(B$2:B$40,B2,B$2:B$40,"*Pub"))>0
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Alright so, instead of using conditional formatting, I had to use a VBA script. After a couple of hours, I've figured it out. Here is the script. It will work with any data, It can be numbers symbols anything it will work. You should be able to just put the script in and run it.

```
Sub MacroTest()
    '
    ' MacroTest Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
    '
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim groupStartRow As Long
    Dim currentData As Variant
    Dim previousData As Variant
    Dim isLightGray As Boolean
    
    ' Find the last row with data in column A
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Initialize groupStartRow
    groupStartRow = 2
    
    ' Initialize previousData with the first cell's value in column A
    previousData = Cells(2, 1).Value
    
    ' Initialize isLightGray to True
    isLightGray = True
    
    ' Loop through all rows from row 3 to the last row
    For i = 3 To lastRow
        ' Get the current data from column A
        currentData = Cells(i, 1).Value
        
        ' Check if the current data is different from the previous one
        If currentData <> previousData Then
            ' Color the background of the group
            If isLightGray Then
                Range("A" & groupStartRow & ":Z" & i - 1).Interior.Color = RGB(211, 211, 211) ' Light Gray
                With Range("A" & groupStartRow & ":Z" & i - 1).Borders
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Color = RGB(192, 192, 192) ' Light Gray border color
                    .Weight = xlThin
                End With
            Else
                Range("A" & groupStartRow & ":Z" & i - 1).Interior.Pattern = xlNone ' No Fill
            End If
            
            ' Toggle the color for the next group
            isLightGray = Not isLightGray
            
            ' Update groupStartRow to the next row
            groupStartRow = i
        End If
        
        ' Update previousData with the current data for the next iteration
        previousData = currentData
    Next i
    
    ' Color the background of the last group based on the final isLightGray value
    If isLightGray Then
        Range("A" & groupStartRow & ":Z" & lastRow).Interior.Color = RGB(211, 211, 211) ' Light Gray
        With Range("A" & groupStartRow & ":Z" & lastRow).Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Color = RGB(192, 192, 192) ' Light Gray border color
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    Else
        Range("A" & groupStartRow & ":Z" & lastRow).Interior.Pattern = xlNone ' No Fill
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a helper column?

I've used the following formula in column "B" (after having set cell "B1" to "TRUE):

```
=IF(A2=A1;B1;NOT(B1))
```

The result looks as follows:

[image]